# Surround data with single quote sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have variable in sql server like

```
DECLARE @Country varchar(max)
SET @Country='GB,US'
```

here country name is stored and separated by comma. i want to change and store the value in
Country variable like ''GB','US','DE','FR''.

so i was trying by using stuff function like

```
DECLARE @Country varchar(max)
SET @Country='GB,US'
SELECT @Country=STUFF((SELECT ''', ''' + @Country
              FOR XML PATH ('')),
              1, 2, '')
print @Country
```

so please me to achieve it. if i could store country name like ''GB','US','DE','FR'' this way into country variable then i can issue a query like

```
select * from my table where country in ( @Country)
```

please help thanks

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974586/variable-in-expression-in-sql

Comment: see this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773539/sqlcasting-a-string-to-ids-with-in-clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it this way because `@country` is still seen as a single variable to SQL Server, not an array (there is no such thing as an array in SQL Server).

A couple of workarounds:

1 generate dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE country IN (' + CHAR(39) 
    + REPLACE(@Country, ',', CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39)) 
    + CHAR(39) + ');';
```

2 dump the comma-separated values into a split TVF (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195278/splitting-a-column-in-sql-then-looking-up-each-one-in-another-table) for an approach, or [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup) for perf comparisons of multiple approaches).

Comment: Because `CHAR(39)` is prettier than `''''''`. `CHAR(39)` is a single quote and when you want a string to contain one you need to escape it with an extra single quote. When you want to embed that string into another string you need to escape both again, and surround them. It gets ugly and hard to read pretty fast.

Answer (score -2):

Or, if you do not want to use dynamic code:

```
DECLARE @my TABLE (country VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @my
SELECT country FROM (VALUES ('GB'),('US'),('DE'),('FR')) t(country)

DECLARE @Country varchar(max)
SET @Country='GB,US'

SET @Country = CASE WHEN LEFT(@Country, 1) <> ',' THEN ',' ELSE '' END
                  + @Country +
               CASE WHEN RIGHT(@Country, 1) <> ',' THEN ',' ELSE '' END

SELECT * FROM @my WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + country + ',', @Country) > 0
```

Comment: Assume the string `'GB,US'` comes in as a parameter. Can you suggest how to construct your `VALUES` clause (even if the user is on SQL Server 2008 or better, since that syntax won't work on earlier versions)?

Comment: the way u show to solve this trick is very bad...in my case 'GB,US' will come as param.